# SQL: How to add multiple records in table based on variable amount which differs per value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A like this:

| SKU | Value |
| --- | --- |
| First | 5 |
| Second | 3 |

I want to add records to a table B, based on the records in table A.
Table B should be looking like this:

| SKU | Number |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| First | 2 |
| First | 3 |
| First | 4 |
| First | 5 |
| Second | 1 |
| Second | 2 |
| Second | 3 |

How to do this using SQL `INSERT INTO` statement?

Comment: In which database do you want to do this?

Comment: Just a Microsoft SQL Server database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to expand the rows. For example:

```
with
r as (
  select sku, value, 1 as cur from a
 union all
  select sku, value, cur + 1 from r where cur < value
)
insert into b (sku, n) select sku, cur from r;
```

Result:

```
 sku     n 
 ------- - 
 First   1 
 Second  1 
 Second  2 
 Second  3 
 First   2 
 First   3 
 First   4 
 First   5
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8ab2bf22a8a6d415a2e03e46276aa43e).

Answer (score 0):

You need a table with all  number_list and do join:

```
select sku, number_list
  from (
        select 1 as number_list
         union all
        select 2 as number_list
         union all
        select 3 as number_list
         union all
        select 4 as number_list
         union all
        select 5 as number_list
         union all
        select 6 as number_list
         union all
        select 7 as number_list
         union all
        select 8 as number_list
         union all
        select 9 as number_list
         union all
        select 10 as number_list
        )nb
  join (
        select 'First' as sku, 5 as val
         union
           all
        select 'Second' as sku, 3 as val
       )sk
    on nb.number_list <= sk.val
 order by sku, number_list asc
```